# Gulp não minifica as imagens

Tags: gulp

Eu preciso *minificar* muitas imagens, mas não estou conseguindo com o *gulp*.

Problema: O código *minifica* nenhuma imagem e já verifiquei que todas as imagens estão na pasta.

Estrutura das pastas: Gulpfile está no mesmo nível que a pasta img e dentro da pasta tem as imagens dentro.

Console:

```
gulp-imagemin: Minified 0 images
Finished 'minify-img' after 4.06 s
```

Código:

```
// gulpfile.js
const gulp = require('gulp');
const imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');

gulp.task('minify-img', function () {
   return gulp.src('img/*')
   .pipe(imagemin())
   .pipe(gulp.dest('img/'))
});
```

Resultado Esperado: Minificar todas imagens dentro da pasta *img*

Comment: O que aparece no console?

Comment: gulp-imagemin: Minified 0 images

Comment: Está apontando para pasta correta? Como está a estrutura de pastas do projeto?

Comment: Gulpfile está junto com a pasta img e dentro da pasta  tem as imagens dentro.

Comment: já experimentou [outras opções](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-image)?

Comment: veja se o path da imagem está correto:

`return gulp.src('img/*')` => `return gulp.src('./img/*')`

Comment: se o arquivo gulpfile está dentro da pasta `img`, seria este caso então: `gulp.src('./*')`

Comment: Vou tentar outras opções, mas queria saber o que está errado já que aparentemente tá seguindo todos os padrões do gulp.